# Relationship between electrostatic pressure and electrostatic energy density at the boundary of conductors

Tags: electrostatics

On page-104 of Griffith, the electrostatic pressure right outside the conductor is given as:

$$ P = \frac{\epsilon_o}{2} E^2$$
This is the same as the expression for electrostatic energy density [(see wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_density),

$$ \mu =  \frac{\epsilon_o}{2} E^2$$

What is the physical intuition for the formula for evaluating electrostatic pressure and electrostatic energy being the same in the case of boundary of conductors being the same?